# How to prevent a Java.langNullPointerexception When saving images to parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have modified the anywall application to be able to post pictures to parse.com. The applicaton is able to post text and images to parse.com, but it crashes and I get a Java.langNullPointerexception if I post text with out an image to go with that text. I want to be able to post text with or without images.

Here is my code

```
 // UI references.
    private EditText txtEdit_Text;
    private TextView txtCharacter_count;
    private Button btnPost;
    private int maxCharacterCount = Application.getConfigHelper().getPostMaxCharacterCount();
    private ParseGeoPoint geoPoint;

    private String selectedImagePath = "";
    final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;
    private String imgPath;

    private static FrameLayout imagePreviewFrame;
    private  ImageView   imgView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(Application.INTENT_EXTRA_LOCATION);
    geoPoint = new ParseGeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    txtEdit_Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEdit_Text);
    txtEdit_Text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            updatePostButtonState();
            updateCharacterCountTextViewText();
        }
    });

   txtCharacter_count =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCharacter_count);

    btnPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPost);
    btnPost.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    post();
                }
            });

   updatePostButtonState();
   updateCharacterCountTextViewText();

    imagePreviewFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_preview_frame);
      imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_preview);
    //Capture pic

    ImageButton butCamera = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePhoto);
    butCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final Intent intent = new Intent(
                    MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    setImageUri());
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
        }
    });
//Open gallery

    ImageButton butGallery = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnupload);
    butGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, ""),
                    PICK_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}

public Uri setImageUri() {
    // Store image in dcim
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    return imgUri;
}

public String getImagePath() {
    return imgPath;
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            selectedImagePath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
            imgView.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
            imagePreviewFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
            selectedImagePath = getImagePath();
            imagePreviewFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,
                    data);
        }
    }
}

public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
    try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of
        // 2.
        int scale = 1;
        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale *= 2;

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } else
       return null;
}


private void post () {

    String text = txtEdit_Text.getText().toString().trim();
    int Count = 0;

    // Set up a progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(PostActivity.this);
    dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.progress_post));
    dialog.show();
    // Create a post.
    HowzitPost post = new HowzitPost();
    Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getImagePath());
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);

    byte [] image = stream.toByteArray();

    ParseFile file = new ParseFile("images.png",image);

    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String currentuserid = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    arrayList.add(currentuserid);

post.setLocation(geoPoint);
post.setText(text);
post.setTimestamp(time);
post.setVote(Count);
post.setComments(Count);
post.setUser(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
post.setlist(arrayList);
post.setPhotoFile(file);

// Set the location to the current user's location
    ParseACL acl = new ParseACL();
    // Give public read access
    acl.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    acl.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
    post.setACL(acl);

    // Save the post change to save in the background
    post.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private String getPostEditTextText () {
    return txtEdit_Text.getText().toString().trim();
}

private void updatePostButtonState () {
    int length = getPostEditTextText().length();
    boolean enabled = length > 0 && length < maxCharacterCount;
    btnPost.setEnabled(enabled);
}

private void updateCharacterCountTextViewText () {
    String characterCountString = String.format("%d/%d", txtEdit_Text.length(), maxCharacterCount);
    txtCharacter_count.setText(characterCountString);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_post, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Here is my xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PostActivity" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar2"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtEdit_Text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_post"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:gravity="top">
            <requestFocus />

        </EditText>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image_preview_frame"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtEdit_Text"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/image_preview"
                android:layout_below="@id/skootText"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:onClick="removeImage"
                android:text="x"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
        </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnCapturePhoto"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_settings"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCapturePhoto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_picblue"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnupload"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnCapturePhoto"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_vidzb"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hey i think you have forget to save image after to convert into parse file. so first save  ParseFile in background method then to save this image in main query.

Answer (score 0):

Check for null before uploading to server like

```
if(image != null){
  upload();
}
else{
  Toast.makeToast(this,"Null value",200).show(); 
}
```